# Single ('') and Double ("") quotes from Word Document to VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am practicing for my written coding examinations where I will be using Microsoft Word. Every time I copy text from Word into VS Code to run it, VS Code doesn't seem to get the right format for single (`''`) and double quotes (`""`).

[Code in Word Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t8E7.png)

This piece of code is then pasted into VSC.
[Code in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmXQi.png)

Is there a quicker way around this instead of changing them individually? Are there any settings that I can change in Word or VS Code to avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: Really, the answer don't use Word as a code editor - it's not the purpose it was intended for.

Comment: HAHA I have no choice. I am practicing for my written examinations, trying to be less reliant on the curly lines under my buggy code. Should I use notepad instead?

Comment: Yes - notepad is intended as a very basic code editor... it should be perfect for your purposes.

Comment: i just realised Mac doesnt have notepad... @AndyPreston Are you a windows user?

Comment: No, I use Ubuntu... there is a program called TextEdit on the Macintosh which is very much like notepad.
https://www.google.com/search?q=macintosh+text+editor&oq=macintosh+text+editor

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a quicker way around this instead of changing them individually?

Yep. Use the Find and Replace feature (<kbd>ctrl / cmd</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>).

> Are there any settings that I can change in Word or VS Code to avoid this problem altogether?

From your screenshots, this looks like a case of [Word's Smart Quotes feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/smart-quotes-in-word-702fc92e-b723-4e3d-b2cc-71dedaf2f343), where it changes straight quotation marks (`'` and `"`) to curly quotation marks (`‘`, `’`, `“`, and `”`). You can turn off the Smart Quotes for the duration that you are working on coding in Word. Quoting from the documentation:

> On the File tab, click Options.
>
> Click Proofing, and then click AutoCorrect Options.
>
> 1. In the AutoCorrect dialog box, do the following:
> 2. Click the AutoFormat As You Type tab, and under Replace as you type, select or clear the "Straight quotes" with “smart quotes” check box.
> 3. Click the AutoFormat tab, and under Replace, select or clear the "Straight quotes" with “smart quotes” check box.
> 4. Click OK.

If you are on macOS, see under Word > Preferences > AutoCorrect instead.